# Kinect joint detection from top

Tags: kinect, xbox360

I'm wondering, does the Kinect detects joints correctly when it's put on the top (on the ceiling).
I don't have necessary equipment to attach it to ceiling and test, but was wondering whether it reliably detects human. I'm ok even if it confuses the joints, actually.
Has anybody tested this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen while using it, the skeleton detection is iffy from any angle other than directly pointing at a person's front or back. A Kinect pointed straight down with people walking under it would almost certainly not detect anyone, because the human form from above does not look anything like it does from the front. I have had the Kinect pick up random people around me in odd positions (sitting, viewed from the side, etc), but the joints were largely spastic. If you have it mounted on the ceiling and pointed downwards at a sufficient angle to still see people from the front instead of from above.. it could do a fairly good job of picking them up.

So when you say on the ceiling do you mean pointing straight down or still looking at a fairly horizontal angle?

Comment: Basically, I was trying to implement a simple ground game. I project the view to the ground (using projector), use Kinect to detect humans movements and make according actions in this "game". So I guess it's possible to put in sufficient angle (I didn't think about this before), but in that case it will see and detect more people (even outside of playing "board"). I guess it's possible somehow control this?

Comment: Depending on how simple the game is.. you could just use the depth map directly. Just detect the large blobs (people) and track them around your playing field. If you put the Kinect at an angle, you could also use the distance from the camera (included in the skeleton data) to determine whether or not they're actually standing on the player field. This would require some calibration, but it's certainly doable. Just realize that you might not get data about people standing behind each other, which wouldn't be a problem from a top down view.

Comment: Actually putting it on an angle, may force me to implement dynamic  configuration for the camera processing. What I mean is that game has to take into consideration parameters like height of the ceiling, angle, distance to the field etc. which vary from place to place. So I guess putting it on top and using depth information would me more reliable and make it easier to change environment.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of testing with the Kinect mounted in a very high position (2.5 m, 70° to the ground). As answered by Coeffect it just doesn't work. It doesn't work with Microsoft SDK nor with OpenNI. What I can add is that the skeleton recognition only works if the user is facing the camera with her/his whole body-front. Even worse, both frameworks seem to expect the head at the top of the depth-frame.