# Kinect: How to obtain a skeleton from back view?

Tags: kinect

Why should you ever want something like this?
I want to track a single user that is mounted above the ground in a horizontal position. The user is facing downwards to allow free movement of legs and arms. Think of swimming for example.

- I **mounted** the Kinect **at the ceiling facing downwards** so I have a free view of all extremities.
- The sensor is **rotated 90° in z-axis** to have the maximum resolution (you're usually taller than wide).

Therefore the user is seen from the backside, rotated by 90°. It is impossible to get a proper skeleton from OpenNI 1.5. My tests showed that OpenNI is expecting the user facing the camera with the head up in y-axis (see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14496274/275195)). Microsofts SDK is the same but I excluded it here because it won't allow you to change the source code and cannot be adapted. OpenNI 2.0 is not working with the current [SensorKinect](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect) to interface the Kinect in Linux. So:

**Which class is generating the skeleton** in OpenNI 1.5.x?

My best guess would be to rotate the prototype skeleton by y 180° and z 90°. If you know where I could find this.

---

**EDIT**: As I just learned there is no open source software that generates a skeleton from depth images so I fall back to the question in the header:

How can I get a user **skeleton from a rotated back view**?

Comment: "Microsofts SDK ... won't allow you to change the sources." - What do you mean by "sources"?  If `source == sensor` then this is untrue -- it is possible to switch the sensor source.  Are you referring to something else with "source"?

Comment: @ECM With sources I meant the source code. If the depth image y-axis is hard coded as the up-vector in the source code it is not possible to adapt the skeleton-recognition to this setup. I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: I just found an open source project for skeleton tracking: [Skeltrack](https://github.com/joaquimrocha/Skeltrack). Unfortunately it tracks only the upper body part currently.